# ML-Agentsのチュートリアルで「Heuristic method called but not implemented. Returning placeholder actions.」 と出て先に進めない

Tags: c#, unity3d

ML-Agentsのチュートリアルにて、ドキュメント通りにやっても解決できない問題がありましたので質問させて頂きます。
他の質問サイトなども一通り目を通しましたが、どうにもいかず・・・皆様のお知恵をお借りしたい次第です。

こちらがコードとエラーになります

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;

public class RollerAgent : Agent
{
    Rigidbody rBody;
    void Start () {
        rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public Transform Target;
    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
       // If the Agent fell, zero its momentum
        if (this.transform.localPosition.y < 0)
        {
            this.rBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.rBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.transform.localPosition = new Vector3( 0, 0.5f, 0);
        }

        // Move the target to a new spot
        Target.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.value * 8 - 4,
                                           0.5f,
                                           Random.value * 8 - 4);
    }

    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
    // Target and Agent positions
    sensor.AddObservation(Target.localPosition);
    sensor.AddObservation(this.transform.localPosition);

    // Agent velocity
    sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.x);
    sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.z);
    }
    

    public float forceMultiplier = 10;
    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actionBuffers)
    {
        // Actions, size = 2
        Vector3 controlSignal = Vector3.zero;
        controlSignal.x = actionBuffers.ContinuousActions[0];
        controlSignal.z = actionBuffers.ContinuousActions[1];
        rBody.AddForce(controlSignal * forceMultiplier);

        // Rewards
        float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.localPosition, Target.localPosition);

        // Reached target
        if (distanceToTarget < 1.42f)
        {
            SetReward(1.0f);
            EndEpisode();
        }

        // Fell off platform
        else if (this.transform.localPosition.y < 0)
        {
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }

    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut)
    {
        var continuousActionsOut = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;
        continuousActionsOut[0] = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        continuousActionsOut[1] = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

}
```

[image: コンソールの画像]

エラー(警告)の方は、Playボタンを押すと継続的に出てくるようになっており、ドキュメントでは「十字キーでAgent(ボール)を操作出来る」とあるものの、操作も効かない状態です。

OS：macOS Venture 13.1

ML-Agents:Release20

ドキュメント：
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/develop/docs/Learning-Environment-Create-New.md

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決致しました。

他のサイトにて「Agent(Script)をデタッチすると治る」とのことでしたので試してみたところ、

```
InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling to Input System package in Player Settings.
```

というエラーが

しかしこれは設定を変えると治るとのことでしたので、

Edit->ProjectSettings->Player->Active Input Handling のチェックボックスを「both」に変更

するとエラーも無くなり、自分で操作できるように！

ちなみに`Fewer observations(0) made...`のエラーも同時に解決しました。

お騒がせいたしました。